# selenium Sendkeys is not working on Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

My aim is to run the selenium login test case on Jenkins. but on the Jenkins it's not working I think the problem is with clicking on the login button and `sendkeys()`. the Jenkins is not able to send the Keys and click on the login button. also, I am not getting the clear error message on Jenkins for what is the exact error

selenium code

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/dev2/Downloads/chrome2.46/chromedriver");
WebDriver m1 = new ChromeDriver();
m1.get("https://www.gateway.com/serviceforecasting/index.php?mode=report");
m1.manage().window().maximize();
// LOGIN
m1.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='userEmailID']")).sendKeys("jbg@autods.com.au");
m1.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@name='userPassword']")).sendKeys("adinjbg");

m1.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='submit']")).click();
```

Jenkins console:

```
Xvfb starting$ /usr/bin/Xvfb :0 -fbdir /var/lib/jenkins/xvfb-28-..fbdir8052198913172415118
[seffcon] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins2615817096839228288.sh
+ ./cd.sh
[TestNG] Running:
  /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon/cd.xml

Starting ChromeDriver 2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5) on port 27922
Only local connections are allowed.

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Comment: you didnt add any logs in your test thats why its hard to debug your code. Now, do your test work locally fine? if yes, are you running your test in jenkins from localhost of in different server? If you are running on local host , do the browser open fine ?

Comment: I am able to run the test cases like taking a screenshot and checking the text visibility on the web page.  the issue is i don't know whether the Jenkins is able to send the login detail and click on the button.

Comment: right now i am using the ip address  as url for the jenkins . do i need to replace it with localhost to run the test localy .

Comment: How can I open the browser when I run the test from Jenkins. if u have any idea about it please clarify

Comment: If you are using remote webdriver , you are technically running your test in a different server. but if you are using regular webdriver then you can run your test from jenkins and see your browser opening and do the tasks. Now can you share you webdriver code so i can see how you are opening the browser in selenium?

Comment: i have added selenium code in the question. please check

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/dev2/Downloads/chrome2.46/chromedriver");
WebDriver m1 = new ChromeDriver();
m1.get("https://www.gateway.com/serviceforecasting/index.php?mode=report");
m1.manage().window().maximize();
// LOGIN
m1.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='userEmailID']")).sendKeys("jbg@autods.com.au");
m1.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@name='userPassword']")).sendKeys("adinjbg");

m1.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='submit']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

can you remove the "." from your xpath because the rest of the code looks fine to me
so the login will be like this

```
// LOGIN
m1.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='userEmailID']")).sendKeys("jbg@autods.com.au");
m1.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='userPassword']")).sendKeys("adinjbg");

m1.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
```

Comment: still not working .when I run the build it's getting failed within a second. i think its not even launching the browser screenshot -https://prnt.sc/naxg85